# Trouble with titleForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, header

I am creating a tableview that moves a goal once it is selected to another tableview. However, when I select a cell from the first tableview, I get a Fatal error: Index out of range on line "return sections[section]" in the second view controller. The program runs properly without the use of a header. How would I fix this so that it runs and displays a header view for each section?

Here is my code for the first tableview.

```
import UIKit

class GoalsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var goals: [String] = ["goal 1", "goal 2", "goal 3"]
var valueToPass = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        let viewController = segue.destination as! GoalsTwoViewController
        viewController.goals.append([valueToPass])
        }
    }

}

extension GoalsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return goals.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GoalCell_1", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = goals[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    valueToPass = goals[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        goals.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        if goals.count != 0 {
            showGoalSelected()
            tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

Here is my code for the second tableview.

```
import UIKit

class GoalsTwoViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var goalTableView: UITableView!

let sections: [String] = ["Mark as Complete:", "History:"]
var goals: [[String]] = [[], []]
let theEmptyModel: [String] = ["No data in this section."]

extension GoalsViewTwoController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return goals[section].count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodayGoalViewCell_1", for: indexPath) as? GoalTableViewCell
            cell?.goalLabel.text = goals[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            cell?.cellDelegate = self
            cell?.index = indexPath
            return cell!
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return goals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            progressBarAnimation()

            if goals[0] != theEmptyModel {
                goals[1].append(goals[0][indexPath.row])
                if goals[1].first!.contains("No data in this section.") {
                    goals[1].removeFirst()
                }
                goals[0].remove(at: indexPath.row)
                if goals[0].count == 0 {
                    goals[0].append(contentsOf: theEmptyModel)
                }
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

Comment: On which line are you getting a crash?

Comment: return sections[section] in the extension of the GoalsTwoViewController

Comment: `numberOfSections(in tableView:)`returns `goals.count`. `tableView(_ tableView: titleForHeaderInSection:)` returns `sections[section]`. Who told you that `sections.count == goals.count` What do you think is doing `viewController.goals.append([valueToPass])` to `goals`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var goals: [[String]] = [[], []] // wrong
var goals: [[String]] = [] // It would be like this

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if goals.indices.contains(section) {
        return goals[section].count
    }
    return 0
}
```

Run and check again

Comment: Thanks, but now only one section view is displayed as opposed to two.

Comment: I get an error on the line, return goals[section].count, in the GoalTwoViewController that says 'Fatal error: Index out of range' when I try to click on the cell.

Comment: Please check the above my code, I have just updated

Answer (score 0):

Modify you `numberOfSection` as follows:

```swift
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}
```

Comment: when I run this I no longer see the tableview cell being added to the second table view.

Comment: @k-12345 That is out of the scope of this question. This answer is meant to solve the crash. Post another question, if you have more doubts unrelated to this question.